# MessageBodyReader for application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.Set

Tags: java, rest, quarkus

i'm trying to send files via Quarkus multipart form. Sending one File or Files works fine, Receving a collection of Files result in the error

```java
RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.Set
```

My DTO looks as follows

```java
public class TestDto {

    @FormParam("files")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Set<File> files;

}
```

Using the following service

```java
public interface TestService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @MultipartForm
    public TestDto getTest();
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a `List` instead of a `Set`? That should works

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci

The error just changes to List

` java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.List`

Comment: Using a `org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload` in behalf of `File` give better result?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Unfournatly this is not a reactive application. So I don't have access to FileUpload